Is it possible to enable hugepages for both postgres and another service?
Suppose I have a instance of postgresql server v16 with 10GB of shared buffers. Having default hugepage size equal to 1gb, I need 11 hugepages for postgresql and works fine.
How should I configure hugepages in a Rocky Linux 8 environment and postgresql 16 if I have another service/program running in the same machine, which also needs N hugepages.
I tried to set up N + 11 hugepages but doesn't work since postgresql does not start.
